# How to stream an XElement/XDocument with WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have the following method signature. I cannot change it (i.e. I cannot change the return type).

```
public Stream GetMusicInfo(string songId)
{
    XElement data = dao.GetMusicInfo(songId);

    // how do I stream the XElement?
}
```

How can I stream the XElement/XDocument with WCF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's reasonably simple, if you don't mind *actually* fetching all the data in that first line:

```
public Stream GetMusicInfo(string songId)
{
    XElement data = dao.GetMusicInfo(songId);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    data.Save(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    return ms;
}
```

In other words, just write it out in-memory, and return a stream over that in-memory representation. Note the `Position = 0;` call, which is necessary as otherwise the stream will be positioned at the *end* of the data.

I would *hope* that WCF would then just do the right thing with the stream.

Comment: Any idea why I am getting this: HTTP/1.1 504. ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request?

Comment: Never mind. I found the issue. I was doing "using (MemoryStream ms...)". Any idea why the using is causing that? My return statement was inside the using.

Comment: Because it would return the stream and right after that dispose it (before WCF could start sending the stream back to the client).

Comment: @Martin: Right, yes, that would foul it up.